# PDF Generator in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This code I have in the products controller Index Method:

```
  def index

    @products = Product.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = PDF::Writer.new
        @products.each do |product|
          pdf.text product.name 
        end        
        send_data pdf.render, :filename => 'products.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline'
      end
    end   
  end
```

and in 
environment.rb file

```
require 'pdf/writer'

Mime::Type.register 'application/pdf', :pdf
```

While running the program I am getting the error

> undefined method `each' for "Pen":String

Comment: What versions of ruby, rails and PDF::Writer are you using? Which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: i am using rails 3.2.12 and in gem file i added gem 'pdf-writer' i am getting error in @products.each do |product| as "undefined method `each' for "Pen":String"

Answer (score 2):

Aha. According to [PDF::Writer's home page](http://ruby-pdf.rubyforge.org/pdf-writer/index.html), "PDF::WRITER HAS BEEN DISCONTINUED AS OF APRIL 15th, 2010. PLEASE USE ITS SPIRITUAL SUCCESSOR, PRAWN INSTEAD."

I've personally been very happy using prawn to generate PDF's. But to directly answer your question, my guess is that you're probably using ruby 1.9.x, which changed the String API a bit, and PDF::Writer is meant for ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1):

use metaskills-pdf-writer gem. This error is happening because the each method of strings on Ruby 1.8 has changed at version 1.9. So this no longer works on new versions of ruby. This gem i mentioned will fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you   Your answer saved me countless hours 